# Combinig .wav files in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, filestream

I was trying to get the code from this article to work in Unity: [Concatenating Wave Files Using C# 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15187/Concatenating-Wave-Files-Using-C-2005). After some tinkering, I ran the script but Unity outputs a file that is not recognized. It has .wav at the end but the importer says it is Unknown rather than Native(Wav). Is there something else I have to do to get Unity to output the file as a recognized .wav?

Comment: If concatenting wav files is not an integral part of your application's functionality, you can you use audacity or other specialised software like described in this [thread](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums//lofiversion/index.php/t30744.html).  Can you play the resulting wav file in other applications?

Comment: nvm, I have a different question now since I went with different code that seems to generate a working wav file